# CalendarExtender en ASP.NET ¿donde se encuentra el "OnClick" del evento "today"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

Buen día estoy teniendo un problema en asp, con el calendario extender que ofrece ajax. 
Lo que ocurre es que al presional "today" en el navegador google chrome no hace nada, sólo se cierra el calendario. Lo que me parece raro es que funciona correctamente en mozilla e internet explorer. Entonces puede ser posible que sea una configuración incompatible con chrome?

Alguien alguna vez le ah ocurrido ? Dejo una screen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade este atributo en la etiqueta del control: SelectedDate="<%# DateTime.Today %>"

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta lo probaré ya mismo.